# Quickbooks SDK - Lot number from sales order

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

Is it possible to get the lot number from a sales order using the quickbooks QBFC SDK.

I have the code running and working, but lot number doesn't come through the QBFC SDK.

Lot number is there in the sales order in quickbooks.

How do I get lot number from a sales order via the SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although the SDK has fields for the Serial / Lot numbers, they currently don't return any information on a SalesOrder. This functionality hasn't been implemented in the latest version of the SDK (13.0). The only way that I know of to get this information would be to do a CustomDetailReportQueryRq and filter the report with the following:

- ReportTxnTypeFilter = SalesOrder
- ReportDetailLevelFilter = AllExceptSummary
- ReportPostingStatusFilter = NonPosting
- SummarizeRowsBy = TotalOnly
- IncludeColumn = SerialOrLotNumber

You will probably want to add in the columns for RefNumber, TxnID, and ItemName to help parse out the values that you need.